# Get NameSpace of my Test Class

Tags: c#, dll, webdriver, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I have a webdriver solution that has 10 or so projects in it.  1 core assembly/dll that holds all the common methods and 9 other test assemblies that use those methods in their tests.

I need to access an embedded resource for one of those 9 assemblies but I need to do it from inside the core dll.  What's the best way to do that.

```
namespace = webdriver.core 
json.cs - reads a json file and returns it as a string

namespace = webdriver.marketplacestest 
marketplace1Test.cs - calls one of the methods in json.cs such as getName();
profile.json - holds {"marketplace1" : "Amazon"}
```

calling an embedded resource from a known namespace is easy.  I did that like this:

```
private static string fromEmbeddedResource(string myNamespace, string myFolder, string fileName)
{
    string result;
    using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(myNamespace + "." + myFolder + "." + fileName))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return result;

}
```

As you can see, I just call the following and I have the file as a string

```
string json = fromEmbeddedResource("WebDriver.Core", "CFG", "pid.json");
```

It's harder though when the file is embedded in one of my test dlls.  Anyone know how I can access or get the assembly's namespace?  I tried...

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes();
```

but it looks like it's pulling types from the WebDriver.Core.dll assembly and not the WebDriver.Marketplace1.dll assembly.

Comment: string testNamespace = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name; that gives me the correct name but I'm still getting null on the using(StreamReader reader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  The problem I had was the calling assembly wasn't the correct assembly because I was calling a method in my core dll that called another method in my core dll. I got it working by passing the assembly along but that was expensive.  To make things more efficient I modified my static SettingsRepository class that holds the two assemblies in a dictionary.  That way I can pass in a string of "core" or "test" and pull the assembly without having to determine if I'm using an executing assembly or calling assembly each time.

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> _assembly = new Dictionary<string,object>();
public static Assembly getAssembly (string type)
{
    return _assembly[type] as Assembly;
}
public static void addAssembly(string myType, Assembly assembly)
{
    bool containsKey = _assembly.ContainsKey(myType);
    if (!containsKey)
    {
        _assembly.Add(myType, assembly);
    }
}
```

When I start a test, I always initialize my driver class first so i added the following two sets to that constructor.

```
Settings.addAssembly("core", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
Settings.addAssembly("test", Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

Now I can call either assembly I want anytime I want and know which one I'm getting.